# How to convert a string (Thu Mar 16 11:30:13 IST 2017) to required format in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a string in the format mentioned above .
Need to form a select query for Oracle to show the date in DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS

Comment: Yes this is tried ... But input is valid for the function. Trying to get some way so that input and output format is given by me with the input

Comment: If I understand the requirement correctly, you can use a combination of `TO_CHAR` and `TO_STRING`. Can you give us the exact input and output that you are expecting, with examples.

Comment: @Arun, string `Thu Mar 16 11:30:13 IST 2017` certainly does not match format `DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit- Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @AyushGoel : Can you just try `SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(REPLACE('Thu Mar 16 11:30:13 IST 2017','IST ',''),'DAY MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY'), 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;` (provided you do not want to change the timezone) ?

Answer (score 2):

This will get it as a date:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
         'Thu Mar 16 11:30:13 IST 2017',
         'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "IST" YYYY'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

This will format it in your desired format:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           'Thu Mar 16 11:30:13 IST 2017',
           'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "IST" YYYY'
         ),
         'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the time zone IST? Problem is, this is ambiguous:

```
SELECT tzName, tzabbrev, TZ_OFFSET(tzName)
FROM v$timezone_names 
WHERE tzabbrev = 'IST';

TZNAME  TZABBREV    TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)
Asia/Calcutta   IST +05:30
Asia/Colombo    IST +05:30
Asia/Dacca  IST +06:00
Asia/Dhaka  IST +06:00
Asia/Gaza   IST +02:00
Asia/Hebron IST +02:00
Asia/Jerusalem  IST +02:00
Asia/Karachi    IST +05:00
Asia/Kathmandu  IST +05:45
Asia/Katmandu   IST +05:45
Asia/Kolkata    IST +05:30
Asia/Tel_Aviv   IST +02:00
Asia/Thimbu IST +06:00
Asia/Thimphu    IST +06:00
Atlantic/Reykjavik  IST +00:00
Eire    IST +00:00
Europe/Dublin   IST +00:00
Iceland IST +00:00
Israel  IST +02:00
```

Let's assume it is always local time and time zone value could be ignored. In this case you can use this one:

```
TO_DATE(
   REGEXP_REPLACE(
      'Thu Mar 16 11:30:13 IST 2017', 
      '\w+ +(\w+) +(\d+) +(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+(\d{4})', 
      '\1 \2 \3 \4'), 
   'Mon dd hh24:mi:ss yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american')
```

The result will be according to your current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` settings. Either change that with `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'` or surround expression above by

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(...), 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```